# Magento sorting collection

Tags: magento

all! I have a collection, but wheni try to sort it, i have no success. there is my code:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('novaposhta/warehouse')->getCollection();
$collection->addFilter('city', $city, 'OR');
$collection->addFilter('city_ru', $city, 'OR');
$collection->setOrder('number', 'ASC');
$warehouses = $collection->load();
```

printing select

```
echo $warehouses->getSelect();
```

gives me

```
SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `module_warehouse` AS `main_table` WHERE (city='Kiev') OR (city_ru='Kiev') ORDER BY number ASC
```

but collection still goes unsorted. Any ideas?

Comment: Providing users with a few sample rows that lead you to believe the query is sorted incorrectly may help them answer the question. Also, if you run the SQL query manually does it sort correctly?  Also, is `number` actually a numeric field?

Comment: number has int(3) type. If i run query mannualy in phpMyAdmin - it works correctly. Results goes lik this: Отделение № 10 (до 30 кг): просп. Мира, 37 17,00 грн
Отделение №9 (до 30 кг): ул. Витрука, 9а 17,00 грн
Отделение №11: ул. Щорса, 94 17,00 грн
Отделение № 12 (до 30 кг): ул. Адмирала Щастного, 1/1 17,00 грн
Отделение №13 (до 30 кг): ул. Московская, 26 17,00 грн
Отделение №8: ул. Баранова, 52 17,00 грн
Отделение № 7 (до 30 кг): ул. Киевская, 112 17,00 грн
Отделение №3 (до 30 кг): ул. Якира, 3 17,00 грн
Отделение №2 (до 30 кг): ул. Маршала Рыбалко, 28 17,00 грн